# Why is this a constituent?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

This is a linguistics question but I thought it related to english so I'm also posting here:

[image]

I have the following tree structure, and I don't understand why "of the lane" is a constituent?

The tests I know for constituency are:

Movement/Clefting

Substitution

Question/Answer

Comment: If _toward the end of the lane_ is a constituent, so is _of the lane_; they're both PPs. There are lots more tests for constituency. See Chapter 3 of McCawley (1998).

Comment: Regarding PP's: http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=book/export/html/148 ; the section headed functions talks of constituents. Also here: your sentence is broken down into the various word functions: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091017224619AAIZtK5

Answer (score 1):

I think that clefting works here:

'Twas of the lane that a jogger ran toward the end.

This does sound clunky and antique (the *'twas* doesn't help with this), but it is a grammatical sentence.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Movement/Clefting**

Your example sentence involves a PP *[<sub>PP</sub> of the lane]* contained within another PP, *[<sub>PP</sub> toward the end [<sub>PP</sub> of the lane]]*. It is very difficult to manipulate, specifically, extract out of, complex structures of this kind. (See for example, [A-over-A Principle](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/A-over-A)).

> (1) a. A jogger ran toward the end [<sub>PP</sub> **of the lane**].
>            b. *? [<sub>PP</sub> **Of what**] did a jogger run toward the end. (question)
>            c. *? [<sub>PP</sub> **Of the lane**], a jogger ran toward the end. (topicalization)
>            d. *? It was [<sub>PP</sub> **of the lane**] that a jogger ran toward the end. (it-cleft)

If you simplify the sentence but keep the constituent "the end of the lane" as in the original, you can apply the relevant tests.

> (2) a. The jogger finally reached the end [<sub>PP</sub> **of the lane**].
>            b. [<sub>PP</sub> **Of what**] did the jogger finally reach the end? (question)
>            c. [<sub>PP</sub> **Of the lane**], the jogger finally reached the end. (topicalization)
>            d. It was [<sub>PP</sub> **of the lane**] that the jogger finally reached the end.

2) **Substitution**

You can substitute PPs with pronominal adverbs as pro-forms. The correct pro-form in this case is *thereof*.

> (3) A jogger ran toward the end [**thereof**].

3) **Question/Answer**

For the same reason that you cannot easily move the *of*-phrase out of the *toward*-phrase in your particularly complex example, you cannot easily build a pair of question and answer fragment. 
However, you can work around that by forming an "echo-question", where the interrogative items appear in the same place as the original PP, and for which you need a particularly emotial pragmatic context.

> (4) A: A jogger ran toward the end [<sub>PP</sub> **of the lane**].
>               B: Excuse me!? A jogger ran toward the [<sub>PP</sub> **OF WHAT**]???
>            A: [<sub>PP</sub> **Of a lane**]. Why does that upset you so much?